# Multiplication using repetitive addition

Tags: c, for-loop, multiplication

Why this code is working ? I meant that if “b” is negative then “c” will never achieve the value of “b” in “if statement” and answer should not come right but still irrespective what “b” is (positive or negative) ,the multiplication always comes right . Why ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c=1,d=0;
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    for( ; ; ){
        d=d+a;
        if(c==b)
            break;
        c++;
    }
    printf("%d",d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably something to do with [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), which I thiiiiink is implementation defined in C for signed types. `c` has a max positive value, when you add one more beyond that, it's probably wrapping around to its max negative value. Eventually `c==b` when `b` is negative. If that's what's happening, I wouldn't expect `d` to have the expected result tho, so .. ?

Comment: Always test the return value of calls like `scanf()`. You may have had incomplete input.

Comment: Tip: Where the interactive version is broken, consider using fixed, known-good values to isolate the problem. This is where breaking things up into functions with well defined inputs and outputs helps considerably.

Comment: @yano I believe signed integer overflow in particular is [undefined behavior](https://www.wikiod.com/w/C_Undefined_behavior#Signed_integer_overflow). So there might be a higher chance of this not working on all systems :/

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Indeed it is. OP could try [this version](https://godbolt.org/z/3W1678x65) of the program to catch it.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 right you are. From SO's old documentation: https://www.wikiod.com/w/C_Undefined_behavior#Signed_integer_overflow

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put 3 * -4 and i got this output of b and c:

```
b: -4 c: 1
b: -4 c: 2
b: -4 c: 3
b: -4 c: 4
b: -4 c: 1431655762
b: -4 c: 1431655763
b: -4 c: 1431655764
b: -4 c: 1431655765
b: -4 c: 1431655766
b: -4 c: 1431655767
b: -4 c: 1431655768
b: -4 c: 1431655769
b: -4 c: -1431655769
b: -4 c: -1431655768
b: -4 c: -1431655767
b: -4 c: -1431655766
b: -4 c: -1431655765
b: -4 c: -1431655764
b: -4 c: -1431655763
b: -4 c: -1431655762
b: -4 c: -4
```

as you can see it goes several times throw all integer values and finally get the desired result. (I printed only when d was in the range of [-12, 12] to simplify the message).

Answer (score 0):

```
long long int mult(int a, int b)
{
    long long int result = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < abs(b); x++)
    {
        result += abs(a);
    }
    if((a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0)) result = -result;
    return result;
}
```

```
long long int mult(int a, int b)
{
    long long int result = 0;
    int c = a;
    while(c)
    {
        result += b;
        c += (a > 0 ? -1 : 1);
    }
    if((a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0)) result = result < 0 ? result : - result;
    else result = result < 0 ? -result : result;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why this code is working ?

Your program has *undefined behavior* because of signed integer overflow. It appears to work - because that's one possible outcome of undefined behavior. The same piece of code - in a different part of your program - may behave totally different.

I've modified your code to instead catch the signed integer overflow if you for example enter `3` `-4`:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool overflow(int d, int a) {
    if(a > 0) {
        if(d > INT_MAX - a) return true;
    } else if(a < 0) {
        if(d < INT_MIN - a) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c = 1, d = 0;

    if(scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != 2) {
        printf("input failure\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for(;;) {
        if(overflow(d, a)) {
            printf("%d + %d would result in signed integer overflow\n"
                   "undefined behavior avoided by exiting instead\n", d, a);
            return 1;
        }
        d = d + a;
        if(c == b) break;
        c++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output when entering `3` `-4`:

```
2147483646 + 3 would result in signed integer overflow
undefined behavior avoided by exiting instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, your version of the for loop "for( ; ; )" is essentially an infinite loop. Interestingly, the reason your code works is because of your infinite loop.

On line 10 with your "c++;" statement, when we enter a negative answer for b, we go over the integer max limit 2147483647. Once we go over that limit by 1, c becomes -2147483648 (the integer min limit). This continues until c increments to whatever the negative b value is.

The reason your "d" integer gives the correct answer is the same logic as above. The increment of a will either go to the integer max and min (depending on if your a is positive or negative) to get the correct value with your current code.

For example:
Enter:
3 -4

In the program:
d = 0 + 3
c = 2

...
d = -2 (at this point we've gone past the integer max twice and min once)
c = 2147483647

...
d = -12
c = -4

Comment: "_Once we go over that limit by 1, c becomes -2147483648 (the integer min limit)_" - An `int` may be as small as 16 bits and as large as the number of bits in `intmax_t` . What happens when you go over the limit is undefined behavior. You may get -2147483648 in every program you write for 20 years - until suddenly, you don't, and probably will be very surprised. :-)